# RMySQL fetch - can't find inherited method

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

Using RMySQL I want to load data from a database into a dataframe in R. For this I'm using the following code:

Rconnectdb:

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
user="root", password="password",
dbname="prediction", host="localhost")
```

Main code

```
library(RMySQL)
source("Rconnectdb") #load the database connection
query = "select received,isRefound from message" #specify query
rs=dbGetQuery(con,query) #resultset
dataset <- fetch(rs, n=-1) #fill dataset with all rows of the resultset
dbClearResult(rs) #clear resultset
```

Executing this I get the following error

> Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function "fetch", for signature "data.frame",
>   "numeric"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mistaking `dbSendQuery` with `dbGetQuery`.
`dbGetQuery` combine `dbSendQuery`, `fetch` and `dbClearResult` as per documentation:

> The function `dbSendQuery` only submits and synchronously executes the SQL statement to the database engine. It does not extracts any records — for that you need to use the function `fetch` (make sure you invoke `dbClearResult` when you finish fetching the records you need).
>
> The function `dbGetQuery` does all these in one operation (submits the statement, fetches all output records, and clears the result set).

From `?dbGetQuery` in package `DBI`.

Comment: thx a lot, my lecturer actually used the wrong function in the script he gave me :/