# RShiny interface for MySQL database input in query

Tags: mysql, r, shiny

I am trying to interface a local database with a RShiny interface. The idea is running queries and having nicely formatted tables as a result.

The code I wrote is:

```
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput(inputId = "table_name",
              label = "Select table",
              choices = c("Table_ID" = "Table_name", "Table_ID2" = "Table_name2")
    ),
    fluidRow(
        column(12,
               tableOutput('table')
               )
        )
    )

server = function(input, output) {
    mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(),
                     user = 'root',
                     password = 'password',
                     dbname = 'dbname',
                     port = 3306
                     )
    Record = reactive( {dbSendQuery(mydb, paste ("select * from", input$table_name, sep = " "))})
    
    data.frame = as.data.frame(fetch(Record))
    
    output$table <- renderTable(data.frame)
}




# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I managed to have it working when there are stable fixed values. But as soon as I try interactivity the app crashes returning the following error.

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7410
Warning: Error in <Anonymous>: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘fetch’ for signature ‘"reactiveExpr", "missing"’
  51: stop
  50: <Anonymous>
  49: fetch
  47: server [server path]
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘fetch’ for signature ‘"reactiveExpr", "missing"’
```

In another post it was suggested to use dbGetQuery instead of dbSendQuery. In my case if I replace the code with:

```
server = function(input, output) {
    mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(),
                     user = 'root',
                     password = 'N355un4!?',
                     dbname = 'breeding',
                     port = 3306
                     )
    Record = dbGetQuery(mydb, paste ("select * from", input$table_name, sep = " "))
    
    output$table <- renderTable(as.data.frame(Record))
}
```

I get another error, which is:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7410
Warning: Error in as.data.frame.default: cannot coerce class ‘c("reactiveExpr", "reactive", "function")’ to a data.frame
  99: stop
  98: as.data.frame.default
  96: renderTable
  95: func
  82: renderFunc
  81: output$table
   1: runApp
```

Any clue on whatis going wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you use `as.data.frame(fetch(Record()))` in `renderTable` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RMySQL fetch - can't find inherited method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726114/rmysql-fetch-cant-find-inherited-method)

Comment: If I do that the App does not crash, but the error remains.

Comment: @Luuk no. If I replace dbSendQuesry with dbGetQuery I get an error telling me that I cannot coerce the result to a dataframe. So I should keep the fetch procedure.

Comment: What happens when you do `Record = reactive({fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb, paste0("select * from", input$table_name)))})` and use `output$table <- renderTable(Record())`

Comment: @RonakShah it works better. But Now I get the error:
```Error in .local: could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fromseed_stock' at line 1
```

Comment: @RonakShah I changed paste0() to paste() and add the sep=" " argument and it works! Thanks so much. Can you explain why the first version was not working?

Comment: I added some explanation as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactive objects are referred with `()`. Also the line `data.frame = as.data.frame(fetch(Record))` should be either inside a reactive expression or `renderTable`.

We can return a dataframe as reactive object and use it to show in `renderTable`.

```
server = function(input, output) {

  mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(),
                   user = 'root',
                   password = 'password',
                   dbname = 'dbname',
                   port = 3306
  )

  Record = reactive({
    fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb, paste("select * from", input$table_name, sep = " ")))
    })
  
  
  output$table <- renderTable(Record())
}
```